# Footer does not position properly despite seemingly correct CSS

Tags: html, css

I am currently working on a webpage where I want to position a footer at the bottom of the page. This is the CSS for the footer (which is a div):

```
#footer {
background-color:black;
position:absolute;
width:100%;
height:100px;
bottom:0;
}
```

The problem is that the footer, instead of being positioned at the bottom of the page, places itself on top of another div. I have made sure that the footer div is not placed within another element, so that is not an issue. Here is a Jsfiddle of a simple prototype of my webpage, note that the images are missing since they are stored locally on my computer: https://jsfiddle.net/oe406v98/

This question should not be marked a duplicate since all footer-related issues uses my CSS as an answer, therefore there must be some kind of disturbance cause by other elements in my example, hence my question differs.

Comment: remove position:absolute ..That might be causing error

Comment: I have tried that, but it doesn't solve my problem.